# 18.04 No wifi/wireless card

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

When I come up from suspend, my computer, which was just connected to working Wifi, will not be able to find any networks. Restarting it used to be fine, but as of a few days ago, that has caused my wireless card to disappear.

Currently, I'm stuck. I've tried turning it on and off in the BIOS, I've tried some drivers, but nothing works reliably. The way it is right now, `rfkill list all` just doesn't show anything. `sudo lshw -class network` and `lspci` make no mention of my network card. I'm pretty sure my card is Intel, though I can't remember the exact spec.

I've tried installing backported drivers, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here's the pastebin of my wireless info, as detailed by the script from Ubuntu Forums:
https://pastebin.com/0X05KMue

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing the card from the computer and reinstalling it to see if it is just a connection issue with the slot?

Comment: No, I haven't opened the laptop. Today I got it to work for about five minutes though, I feel like it wouldn't do that if there was a connection problem.

Comment: @Jeremy31 it worked! There was a loose wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popped open my laptop, turns out a wire was loose. Plugged it back in and tada! Working wifi!